# Invalid number of arguments FANN ошибка

Tags: php, fann

Здравствуйте, установил на свой веб сервер `FANN`.
Запускаю ф-ию `fann_create_sparse()` или `fann_create_standard()` или `fann_create_standard_array()` - ошибка везде одинаковая.
**Пример:**

> fann_create_sparse(): Invalid number of arguments

Сама строка выглядит примерно так:
`$ann = fann_create_sparse(1, 90000, 1, 1);`

Как говорит вики, я указываю правильное кол-во аргументов. Но ошибка опять же появляется и не хочет создавать нейронную сеть.

Comment: В приведенном Вами коде Вы пытаетесь создать сеть с 90000 слоями. Соответственно, функция ожидает получить 90002 параметра. А получает всего 4.

Comment: А с fann_create_standard() тот же принцип? Просто во всех мануалах и примерах, вообще используется ф-ия fann_create(), которая, как я понял, не существует с 1.0.0 версии FANN

Comment: Это где Вы такие мануалы нашли? Официальная документация же гуглится за полсекунды: [fann_create_sparse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fann-create-sparse.php), [fann_create_standard](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fann-create-standard.php).